# In Solidity, can i store the value of keccak_256 in bytes32?

Tags: solidity, keccak

```
var uniqueIdentifier = keccak_256(firstName+LastName+studentId);
```

This line returns me a value and can i store that value in bytes32 in solidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keccak_256 returns a bytes32 and you can store it in a bytes32.

Answer (score 1):

declare your variable as bytes32 as follow

```
  bytes32 uniqueIdentifier = keccak256(firstName,LastName,studentId);
```

**Edit** : as Edmund has indicated, keccack returns the hash of the (tightly packed) arguments = concatenated arguments without padding.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions

Comment: Since firstName, LastName are string and studentID is bytes32, it is showing the following error in solidity online compiler: '+' Not compatible with type string..What should i do?

Comment: You should just be able to pass each string to keccak256() as a separate argument delimited by commas. Solidity will deal with concatenating them together.

Comment: @EdmundEdgar you are right keccack  returns the hash of the (tightly packed) arguments = concatenated arguments without padding